# Change Key in Firebase according to user input without hardcoding the key value in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While I was trying to add the data to firebase database I found that the keys are auto generated. I want to customize key value according to the ID value user input.

This is the code I implemented to save data into database. This code is working with auto-generated key value:

```
btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //create
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { //Create
            dbref = F.irebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DetailsOfCode");
            try {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(description.getText().toString()))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a Description", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code.getText().toString()))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(id.getText().toString()))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an Id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    DCode.setDescription(description.getText().toString().trim());
                    DCode.setCode(code.getText().toString().trim());
                    DCode.setId(id.getText().toString().trim());


                    dbref.push().setValue(DCode); //Here I tried to set customize Key, but always showing error

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    clearControls();
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Data, check again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

I want to get the key value as the "ID" user input.
`DCode.setId(id.getText().toString().trim());` <-- This is the id session and I want this ID to show as the key.

If user enter ID as "1", the key value also want to show as "1". I don't want to hard code the key as"1", "2" for each data input. I want it to implement the key according to ID value.

[image: My database with autogenerated key]

In here I want id:1 as Key:1 .Like this,

```
- DetailsOfCode 
      - 1
         code: "cS3j2A"
         description: "Sample 1"
         id: "1"
```

Comment: So you want to change the random id with numbers? Why would you do that?

Comment: YES, i want to change those random keys with the id user enters

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: I have added the code of Creating(Adding) to database, the sample of database and the output i need.. What else do you want me to upload?  This is a simple code example.

Comment: So to understand better, you want to have an array of objects?

Comment: No sir, I just don't want to change the core of my coding. Just want to change that push() method and change  id as KEY

Comment: Instead of `push()` then, simply use numbers added in `.child(1)` call.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the key value. If I add like this I can only insert one data. I want that key to generate automatically according to the ID value

Comment: That's not possible. That's why there are those pushed IDs.

Comment: Sir, i saw something like this in youtube video where he used this kind of database setting to update data. But he haven't mention how to do that. I am trying to do update session using this.     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rIFcMBvh60